# Adding delay to apply a class in the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-hooks

I need to set a delay to apply for a new class.

This is my situation

```
const [done, setDone] = useState<boolean>(false);
```

Inside a method, I have this

```
const myMethod= () => {
  ....
  ....
  setDone(true)
}
```

And in my button where I want the class delaying when `done` is true, so it is not disabled

```
  <Button 
    disabled={!complete}  
  </Button>
```

Comment: You can delay the setting of disabled using a setTimeout?

Comment: yes, can you show me?

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {/*do something*/}, delayInMS);` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `setTimeout`.

```
const myMethod= () => {
  ....
  ....
  setTimeout(() => {
     setDone(true);
  }, 2000); // setDone will be called after 2s
}
```